# What is the meaning of "non-opaque values" in Java 7?

Tags: java-7

Java 7's `AttributeView` will let you create and update non-opaque values associated with objects in a file system. What does that mean?

Comment: Opaque means "hidden, dull, not-clear"; so non-opaque would be obvious, clear, accessible, visible. Did you want something more detailed?

Comment: Yeah something in detail would be appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

Opaque values are abstract items that you can pass around but can't see or change.  A good example is a file handle provided by the operating system - you can get one and pass it to other functions that require a file handle, but you have no way of knowing what it actually is.

For example, an opaque value of a file might be the physical location of the home block of
the file on a disk - something which exists, but which you are not allowed to read or write.

Answer (score 0):

opaque values are those which can be passed or used only in the same environment. E.g Java arrays are opaque values which can pass only into the java code. If you want something to be used in other platform like JavaScript or JNI you have to use non-opaque values.

For more info: [see this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type).